# Error in writing asynchronous Vows.js Tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, vows

I have been working with node and using vows to write tests.

```
var vows = require('vows');
var assert = require('assert');

var boardData = require('../lib/data/BoardData.js');

vows.describe('Loading provinces and Boundries for').addBatch({
  'version': {
    '2008E5-1':{
      topic: function () { boardData.createBoard("2008E5",this.callback); },
      'exists': function (err,provs,bounds) { assert.ok(true); }
    }/*,
    '2008E5-2': {
      topic: function () { boardData.createBoard("2008E5",this.callback); },
      'exists': function (err,provs,bounds) { assert.ok(true); }
    }*/
  }
}).export(module);
```

When I Run this code I get the expected results.
When I uncomment the commented section notice that two completed successfully but one can discover that is the second one twice by placing a console.log("foo"); in the proper location.

```
·· ✓ OK » 2 honored (0.067s)
·
✗ Errored » callback not fired
  in version 2008E5-1
  in Loading provinces and Boundries for
  in undefined
```

This must be that I am missing something or lack the understanding of something, but I cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like boardData.createBoard isn't calling the callback.

Comment: It calls it when the code has the comment in it runs. Using a simple console.log("foo"); inside the callback show that it does.
    'exists': function (err,provs,bounds) { console.log("foo"); assert.ok(true); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It concerns me that the "version" key doesn't have a topic. I think it needs a topic of its own. You can nest sub-topics under it if you need to.

Or, run it with the `--spec` option to see exactly what tests are being run.

```
vows --spec
```

or

```
./node_modules/vows/bin/vows --spec
```

Answer (score 0):

boardData.createBoard contains other is an async calls and apparently that is not allowed (and should be done in a setup?). No evidence, just experiments.